# What IDE's are available for writing google chrome apps?

Tags: ide, google-chrome-app

I want to start writing a google chrome app but I'd like to use an IDE.  Searching around I haven't come up with much.  Most of my search results are IDEs that are chrome apps rather than for chrome apps.  Does anyone have a suggestion? (I realize I don't /need/ an IDE but I want to know what my options are)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build a Chrome app, you just use the typical client-side web development stack--HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. This means you can use any IDE you would use for building a web front end like WebStorm, Eclipse, Sublime Text, etc.

You can also build Chrome apps with Google Dart, which means you could also use Dart Editor along with WebStorm and the Dart Plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

Happy to report that Google is now working on an open-source IDE specifically targeted at Chrome app development, codenamed Spark. See [this announcement on thenextweb.com](http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/11/21/google-building-chrome-app-based-development-environment-using-dart-polymer/#!qP3Xd) for example. You can find the code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/spark). The IDE is in a very early stage, but progressing quickly. There are no firm plans yet as to when an initial public release in Chrome Web Store will become available, but if you're interested, you can follow announcements on the GitHub page.

UPDATE (08/12/2014): Spark has been officially announced at Google I/O 2014 and released to the public as Chrome Dev Editor. Install it in your Chrome from [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg).

Comment: Quote:
"...Chrome Dev Editor is a developer tool for building apps on the Chrome platform - Chrome Apps and Web Apps, in JavaScript or Dart. (NO LONGER IN ACTIVE DEVELOPMENT)..."

Answer (score 0):

I started Xpom-Xpum! SDK project — a free and open-source IDE for Google Chrome extensions and apps.
If you interested, you can download it and it's C# code (MIT License) by link http://xpomxpum.codeplex.com/
But now I released it's Alpha version only...